# How to make android spinner select from tblContacts

Tags: android, sql, jdbc, android-studio, spinner

I am using jdbc 1.2.8 to connect to MS SQL database, and there I have a tblContacts containing few contact names.

What I am trying to do now it to make my spinner {select * from tblContacts} and populate the list just like a regular spinner.

I am stuck here, I am not really sure what to do at this moment, help is appreciated, thanks.

At this point I have this.

---

```
 Spinner staticSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.brew_array,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);


            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


    staticSpinner.setAdapter(staticAdapter);

    Spinner dynamicSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    String[] items = new String[] { "Android", "AndroidOld", "AndroidNew" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);

    dynamicSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    dynamicSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
            Log.v("item", (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Comment: first of all you have need to get all contacts in a simple String oneby one  and then pass in to List<String> then add here in ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>

Comment: tblContacts is a table from my SQL server.

Comment: add here your database table code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate the data from the database you need to use something similar to the following:

```
    private void loadSpinnerData() {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // On selecting a spinner item
        String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "You selected: " + label,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

In a seperate class, you would need to create the database handler code using something similar to this:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbname";
    private static final String TABLE_LABELS = "table_name";  
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "column_name";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public List<String> getAllLabels(){
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning lables
        return labels;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want a better explanation, I would recommend this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/06/android-populating-spinner-data-from-sqlite-database/